# DDD: Should the application service be placed in backend or the UI

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, service-layer

Some DDD books state like [[1]](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/microsoft-.net-architecting-applications-for-the-enterprise-9780735685352) state that although we have one domain model, we could have several application service layer (some use the terminology service layer). This is due to the fact that the application layer is the interface between a specific UI of an application to the domain model and the infrastructure layer and therefore there could be multiple application service layer if we have multiple User Interfaces working with the backend. This point raises the question to me where to locate the application layer.
I am creating an application with .NET C#. The whole application is in a solution where the UIs (we have three different winforms applications that will use the backend) are separate projects and the backend project (a class library containing the domain layer and the infrastructure layer) is a separate one:

```
-- My Solution 
    |
    +-- Application.UI Number 1
    +-- Application.UI Number 2
    +-- Application.UI Number 3
    +-- Application.Backend
             |
             +-- Domain Layer (Model and Domain Services)
             +-- Infrastructure Layer (Repositories with ORM-Tool)
```

In the samples, I have seen so far the application service layer is placed in the `Application.Backend`. But is this correct based on the fact that we could have different application service layer for each of the UIs? Where do you place the projects `Application.ApplicationLayer1`, `Application.ApplicationLayer2` and `Application.ApplicationLayer3`? Or do you merge all application layers into a single applications service layer?

Esposito et al. [[1]](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/microsoft-.net-architecting-applications-for-the-enterprise-9780735685352) state:

> The presentation and application layers are part of the front end of
> the system;

and they add the application layer in the `Application.UI` project in one of there samples.
Other books like [[2]](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/patterns-principles-and/9781118714706/) have a unique application layer in the backend and not in the front end.
It irritates me to insert the application service layer in the UI. The reason is that the application service layer contains all business use cases of the application. It is the client of the domain model and the infrastructure layer. This means that by putting the application layer in the UI, each UI would have its own application layer. But there is high probability that some of the use cases used in UI-1 is also used in UI-2. Therefore, you would have code duplication.

Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I do see the Application layer as the, only, entry point to the Domain. Application services and/or Event handlers might live in that layer. Visualizing the layers having in mind the Onion architecture, the Application layer wraps the Domain one.

Good that you challenged it, but I think that you already answered it by your self. The Application layer should be part of the backend.

I wouldn't map the services 1-to-1 with the UIs though. I would have separated them by feature or resource. Maybe an additional Write/Read separation with Command and View driven Application services would also be good if it wouldn't create lots of overhead. If your UIs need the same data but transformed or enriched, you might want to solve it in an additional "transformation" layer in between or getting them via a more flexible when querying interface (eg GraphQL)

This is my view on this.